# How do you echo all the images stored in a database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob, echo

I'd like to create a page that displays all images stored in the "store" table of my database called "festival", and for them to be presented in a HTMl table. The images in my database are stored as BLOB.

Comment: You Need to php files - one for the table and one file which displays the image

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: I've tried everything haha, I'm sure there's an easy way to do it I just haven't quite figured out yet.

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to query all images. Then you can display an image saved as blob like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $blobimage ) . '" />';
```

Where `$blobimage` is the variable that contains your image from database